# How to print the final result from a class that calculate power numbers

Tags: java, recursion, printing

Can someone please tell how can I print the result of the following class:

```
public static int power2(int x, int y)
    {
        if (y==0)
            return 1;
        else
            return x*power2(x,y-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        power2(2,2);

    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println(power2(2, 2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can either print it directly :
`System.out.println(power2(2,2));`
Or you can save it to a variable and print it from there like :

```
int result = power2(2,2);
...
print (result);
```